# How to downgrade php version in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apache2, 15.04, php, lamp, tasksel

I am working on a codeigniter project where the system requires php version < 5.6 that is 5.5, but few days ago I have installed ubuntu 15.04 with having LAMP stack installed using tasksel;the tasksel is gives me the latest update to php5.6 which is incompatible to my project;even I have uninstall tasksel LAMP server and installed lamp individually but the problem is not persisted

I have a limited knowledge in linux environment if anybody knows please help me with some resources;I will be highly obliged.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `sudo apt-get remove php5`, then for 5.5 specifically, which was not used in 15.04, you will need to add a source from utopic by opening `/etc/apt/sources.list` in your favorite text editor and adding the following lines `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main` and 
`deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main`. Next, to ensure you get the proper version, open `/etc/apt/preferences` in a text editor and add the following lines

```
Package: * 
Pin: release n=trusty
Pin-Priority: 501

Package: php5
Pin: release n=utopic
Pin-Priority: 502
```

This will ensure that all packages are installed from trusty except for php5, which will be installed from utopic.

As with installing any outdated version of a piece of software, this can introduce security risks that you should consider. Also, this may affect the stability of php5 so keep that in mind.

Comment: i have follow detail mentioned of your suggestion but what is command to install php5.5 because i have removed php5 by your command but still unable to remove cause it's available for tasksel.. any help??

Comment: @TamaghnaBanerjee My recommendation would be to attempt a `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to see if aptitude will rectify the version conflict.